# Uploading images as web developer

Tags: hadith, sin, shirk, fatwa

assalamualaikum!
I am a web developer. And part of my job requires me to upload images of cartoons or 3d characters on websites. I just want to know that Is it shirk to to do so or not. Since i did not make these myself and i would not protome such things. I am just uplaoding them but still i cannot help myself but think that it is Shirk?
Although these pictures do not have anything shirk related!

Kindly Guide. JazakAllah

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Of course this is ok. As long as the photos are not for worshipping, you are totally fine!